# isearch `interactive` spec uses special characters for user input

Tags: emacs, elisp

```
(defun isearch-forward (&optional regexp-p no-recursive-edit)
  (interactive "P\np")
  (isearch-mode t (not (null regexp-p)) nil (not no-recursive-edit)))
```

what does special characters `p`(small lettered p) do as args to interactive function? does the first character P (in caps) mean that `regexp-p` value comes from a global var definition.

Again, coming to arguments, user inputted word is passed as regexp-p, how does `no-recursive-edit` gets its value?

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation that describes `interactive codes`:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html#Interactive-Codes

Comment: Or `C-h f interactive RET` (which gives you at least enough information to target a search with the necessary keywords). I've noticed that you've (Madhavan Kumar) asked rather a lot of Emacs questions in recent weeks, and are evidentially interested in programming in elisp. You will do yourself a huge favour by actually taking note of the basics of querying the built-in documentation in Emacs. By now you should *know* that `C-h f` gives you information about a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first letter, `P`, stands for the raw prefix argument, which is the value of variable `current-prefix-arg`.  This is bound to the first formal parameter, `regexp-p` in this case.

This is separated from the second letter, `p`, by `\n` (a newline character). That's the convention for separating inputs in `interactive` specs.

The second letter, `p`, stands for the numeric prefix argument, which is the value of `(prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)`. This is bound to the second formal parameter, `no-recursive-edit` in this case.

Read about this in the Elisp manual, node [`Interactive Codes`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html).

Comment: hi Drew, thanks for explaining. the above func block is bound to Ctrl-s in emacs. here, nowhere user has pressed ctrl-u to set current-prefix-arg. all he does is, ctrl-s, and input his regexp pattern. so, how does prefix-args get their values?

Comment: If the user does not use a prefix arg then `current-prefix-arg` is `nil` and s?he *does not get regexp* search. You can see this from `(not (null regexp-p))`. The *numeric* prefix arg is always an *integer*. If the user does not use a prefix arg then the numeric prefix arg is `1` and `(not no-recursive-edit)` is `nil`. Arg `no-recursive-edit` is `nil` only for some non-interactive calls, never for an interactive call.